# not able to pass value to parent component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to pass the value from the child to parent component. I am new to react please guide me.

This is Greeting component -

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from "react";
const Greeting = props => {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  const name = props.name;

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <h1> Welcome Back {name}</h1>;
  } else {
    return <LoginInfo name={name} onChange={props.onChange} />;
  }
};

function LoginInfo(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Please Login</h1>
      <input type="text" value={props.name} onChange={props.onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Greeting;
```

This is login component -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Greeting from "./Greeting";
import LogoutButton from "./LogoutButton";
import LoginButton from "./LoginButton";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      name: ""
    };
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
  }
  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
  }
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    const name = this.state.name;

    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting
          isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
          name={name}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

I am using in my app.

```
<Login />
```

In greeting component How whatever user entered i can store in state and display in welcome back line with name.

Comment: Where does `name` and `this.handleChange` in `LoginInfo` come from?

Comment: It will be blank input field once user enter we will display.

Comment: Is the plan here to hit an API or do you just want to render what is entered into the input field?

Comment: @James I am just trying to render what is entered.

Comment: you need to pass from your `login` component a `handleChange` handler via `props` (and call it on the child onChange). This way you can update the `state` of your parent when something changes on the child and trigger a rerender

Comment: @japrescott i have updated the code please check.

Comment: Data in React only flows one way - from parent to child. You should pass function references as props to child components and keep function definitions in the parent - [read this for a more detailed explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html).

Comment: I have updated my code based on comments, please check, but still it's not working anything missing.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Thanks for link. I will read.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder assuming I'm reading the question correctly, Darshan's answer should cover everything you need to work out how to make a child component influence a parent's state. Is this not what your question is actually about?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley yes correct, Now it's working, Updated the question, this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to maintain state in your parent component and emit change event from child component and change state in parent.
like

In login component

```
nameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          name: e.target.value
        })
    }

 <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} name={this.state.name} nameChange={this.nameChange}/>
```

and in child

```
<input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={this.props.name}
        onChange={this.props.nameChange}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even I was trying to do something like this. passing the state value from login parent to child greeting. Can you see something in my code which is wrong, please guide.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I would refactor your code for the `LogInInfo` component to pass the values of the user to your `LogIn` component

First of all you need a state in `LogInInfo` since you want to store the values of the user, you will use the state for that

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from "react";
const Greeting = props => {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <h1> Welcome Back</h1>;
  } else {
    return <LoginInfo submitForm={props.handleSubmitForm}/>;
  }
};

class LoginInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Please Login</h1>
        // e is the event that is passed automatically to the function in onSubmit
        <form onSubmit={e => this.props.submitForm(e, this.state.name)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Greeting;
```

At this point you have the value you want to pass to the parent component `LogIn` to pass this value up, you need a function in your parent component that would get this value for you and pass it to the child component so it can be used, we will do this via props. We also need a variable in the parent's state that will store this value

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Greeting from "./Greeting";
import LogoutButton from "./LogoutButton";
import LoginButton from "./LoginButton";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      username: ""
    };
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
  }
  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
  }
  // when you use arrow functions they automatically bind to your component

  handleSubmitForm = (e, value) => {
    // the following line prevents the page from refreshing when you submit any form
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ username: value })
  }

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} submitForm={this.submitForm}/>
        {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

when you click the submit button it should update the state in the `LogIn` component. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks David for answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. create a function which will handle changes of the input in Login component, send it to Greeting and then to LoginInfo. the function would look something like:

   `onChange = (event) => this.setState({event.target.name: event.target.value})`

   note: event.target.name equals to name prop of input. the function above will work only if the name of the state that stores that input value equals to the input name, in your case **name**.
2. send the state that stores the value of the input to the LoginInfo. the input element should look like this:

   `<input type="text" name="name" value={valueFromLogin} onChange={props.onChangeFromLogin} />`